# jQuery adding div element with condition arrangement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I wanna ask is it possible if we adding `div` element with jQuery, but I need condition like this:

My code before

```
<li>
    <a href="" class="1"></a>
    <a href="" class="2"></a>
    <div class="another"></div>
    <a href="" class="3"></a>
</li>
```

And what I want is:

```
<li>
    <a href="" class="1"></a>
    <div class="new">
        <a href="" class="2"></a>
        <div class="another"></div>
        <a href="" class="3"></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

If it possible, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: and what you've tried so far??

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: What's the criteria for adding the `.new` div?

Comment: look into jquery append http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: `var wrapper = $('<div class="new"/>');
$('li').find('a').first().after(wrapper).nextAll().appendTo(wrapper);`

Comment: @dave post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the new element, append it wherever you want, then append the elements you want into the new element:

```
var wrapper = $('<div class="new"/>'); 
$('li').find('a').first().after(wrapper).nextAll().appendTo(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

The criteria for what you want is not completely clear, but you can try using [`wrapAll`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/): `$(".2, .3, .another").wrapAll("<div class='new' />");`

```js
$(".2, .3, .another").wrapAll("<div class='new' />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="" class="1"></a>
    <a href="" class="2"></a>
    <div class="another"></div>
    <a href="" class="3"></a>
</li>
```